# Problem in serial communication between ESP32 and GSM A7670C

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, gsm

I am using A7670C GSM breakout board with an ESP32.

Connections

- RX-TX
- TX-RX
- GND-GND

I am giving external power to the GSM module, 3.8 V according to theproduct description.

When I sent the AT command to GSM module, I don't get output on the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE.

The message is sent to a particular number successfully, but I don't receive the message from mobile.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial mySerial(2);

void setup() {
  mySerial.begin(115200); // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module
  Serial.begin(115200);   // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  delay(100);
  SendMessage();
  RecieveMessage();
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
    Serial.write(Serial.read());

  switch(Serial.read()) {
    case 's':
      SendMessage();
      break;
    case 'r':
      RecieveMessage();
      break;
  }

  if (mySerial.available() > 0)
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}

void SendMessage() {
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1");    // Sets the GSM Module in Text Mode
  delay(1000);  // Delay of 1000 milli seconds or 1 second
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+91XXXXXXXXXX\"\r"); // Replace x with mobile number
  delay(1000);
  mySerial.println("I am SMS from GSM Module"); // The SMS text you want to send
  delay(100);
  mySerial.println((char)26); // ASCII code of CTRL+Z
  delay(1000);
}

void RecieveMessage() {
  mySerial.println("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0"); // AT Command to receive a live SMS
  delay(1000);
}
```

Other AT commands also don't give me an OK message on the serial monitor, or any other message. I have tried software serial, but it doesn't work.

[image: Phone screenshot]